# TypeError:string indices must be integers

Tags: python, sql, json, django

i am getting following error- "Python: TypeError:string indices must be integers"  and I can not see what's wrong. Am I being stupid and overlooking an obvious mistake here?

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        totalData=[]
        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:

                cursor.execute(order_detail_query)
                order_detail_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_detail_data = list(order_detail_result)
                # print(order_detail_data)

                cursor.execute(order_query)
                order_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_data = list(order_result)

                dic = {}
                for d in order_detail_query:
                    if d['order_id'] not in dic:
                        dic[d['order_id']] = []
                    dic[d['order_id']].append(d)
                return order_data.append(dic)

            totalData.append({"order_data":order_data, "order_detail_data":order_detail_data})
            return Response({"totalData":totalData,},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Towards the bottom, I think you need `for d in order_detail_data:`, not `for d in order_detail_query:`. The latter, which you have, is iterating through the string literal you defined as your query.

Comment: that's helped me. thank you so much! @gooberwonder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lass Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
def get(self,request,format=None):
    totalData=[]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cur,conn = connection()
        order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
        order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

        with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:

            cursor.execute(order_detail_query)
            order_detail_result = cursor.fetchall()
            order_detail_data = list(order_detail_result)
            # print(order_detail_data)

            cursor.execute(order_query)
            order_result = cursor.fetchall()
            order_data = list(order_result)

            dic = {}
            for d in order_detail_data:
                if d['order_id'] not in dic:
                    dic[d['order_id']] = []
                dic[d['order_id']].append(d)
            return order_data.append(dic)

        totalData.append({"order_data":order_data, "order_detail_data":order_detail_data})
        return Response({"totalData":totalData,},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This should work